# How to Create Wizard Page With JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i want to create wizard page like this:

http://i39.tinypic.com/14v0k9h.jpg

Now I want to complete these steps from another page.

and this is code for Next Step :

```
function NextRow() {
            var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl1");
            while (count < tbl.rows.length) {
                if (tbl.rows[count].bgColor != "lightblue") {
                    tbl.rows[count].bgColor = "lightblue";
                    tbl.rows[count].innerHTML = "<td>step " + (count + 1) + "</td>";

                        var dv = document.getElementById("dvText").innerText = tbl.rows[count].title + "  ";

                    if (count >= 0) {
                        tbl.rows[count - 1].bgColor = "white";
                        tbl.rows[count-1].innerHTML = "<td></td>";
                    }
                }
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: -1: Not a question. Please ask a specific question, show us what you've tried so far and where your expected/actual results varied.

Answer (score 1):

I used [jQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org/) few weeks back. Probably, this might save you from not writing the full thing from scratch. See the documentation on the page for usage.

Comment: thanks my friend but i don't want to use jquery

Comment: Probably you have to make on your own then :)

Comment: Yes, I want a simple wizard
Please help me

Comment: Go through the examples from the page and try to implement what you need. Post another question if you face any trouble